# Python program giving me wrong answers

Tags: python-3.x

I am making a program that On a cellar phone plan, a user has 400 minutes that they can use for $20 a month.Then if the user, uses more than 400 minutes in a month, they are charged 5 cents a minute beyond the 400 minutes on their plan.Ask a user for the number of minutes they used this month and then calculate their bill. Make sure you check to see if the person entered a negative integer (Then you should print out “You entered a negative number”).

My Code:

```
def main():
    # the bill will always be at least 20
    res = 20
    # again is a sentinel
    # we want the user to at least try the program once
    again = True
    while again:
        minutes = int(input("How many minutes did you use this month? "))
        # error correction loop
        # in the case they enter negative minutes
        while minutes < 0:
            print("You entered a negative number. Try again.")
            # you must cast to an int
            # with int()
            minutes = int(input("How many minutes did you use this month? "))
        # get the remainder
        remainder = minutes - 400
        # apply five cent charge
        if remainder > 0:
            res += remainder * 0.05
        print("Your monthly bill is: ","$",res)

        det = input("Would you like to try again? Y/N: ")
        again = (det == "Y")    
main()
```

If I type in 600 I get the correct answer which is $30. When it asks to go again I type Y for yes and enter anything lower like 500 and I get the answer $35 which doesn't make sense. And again if you type y and enter something lower the price goes up.It seems like when the minutes go down the price goes up, yet if the minutes go up the price goes up as it should.

What am I doing wrong. And thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move `res` to be inside the loop, so it gets reset. Like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.6


def main():
    # again is a sentinel
    # we want the user to at least try the program once
    again = True
    while again:
        res = 20  # Reset this variable
        minutes = int(input("How many minutes did you use this month? "))
        # error correction loop
        # in the case they enter negative minutes
        while minutes < 0:
            print("You entered a negative number. Try again.")
            # you must cast to an int
            # with int()
            minutes = int(input("How many minutes did you use this month? "))
        # get the remainder
        remainder = minutes - 400
        # apply five cent charge
        if remainder > 0:
            res += remainder * 0.05
        print("Your monthly bill is: ", "$", res)

        det = input("Would you like to try again? Y/N: ")
        again = (det == "Y")


main()
```

The way you had it, `res` just kept incrementing forever, never being reset to 20.

Comment: Oh man how did I not catch that...Thank you! Works perfectly now.

Answer (score 1):

You're not resetting `res` between each try, so every loop, it's added to. It looks like you want every loop to be independent of each other, so this behavior would be unintended.

Right under `while again:`, reset `res` be reassigning it to 20. You probably don't even need to declare `res` outside of the loop in the first place, since it looks like it's only ever used within the scope of the loop.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation